# Assign function return object to variable and pass it to a component as a prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having trouble doing one last thing here. I need to take the object that gets returned from the _request method and assign it to the propVals variable in the render method and then pass that variable to the channelValues prop on the SingleChannel component as you can see. My problem is that propVals is undefined when I return the SingleChannel component. I know the if statements are returning what they should be so the problem is that the SingleChannel component is being rendered before propVals recieves the object. I really have no idea what else to do. I have also tried calling the method directly from the SingleChannel component like channelValues={this._request(channel.name)}.

```
_request(name) {
HTTP.call('GET', `https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/${name}`,
  {headers: {Accept: 'application/vnd.twitchtv.v3+json'} },
  function(error, response) {
    if(error) {
      console.log(error)
    } else {
      if(response.data.stream === null) {
        return {streaming: false, game: "Not playing anything"}

      } else {
        return {streaming: true, game: response.data.stream.game}


      }
    }

  });
}
renderChannels() {
  const channels = this.props.channels;
  console.log(channels)
  return channels.map((channel) => {
    const propVals = this._request(channel.name);
    //console.log(propVals);
    return <SingleChannel key={channel._id} channel={channel} channelValues={propVals}/>

  });


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is AJAX call (Async logic), it is recommended to use `componentDidMount` :

```
componentDidMount:function(){
     var that=this;
     this._request(name,function(){
       that.setState({propVals:propVals})
     });

}
```

In the AJAX callback , call `setState` :

```
_request(name,fnback) {

      //if success 
      fnback.call(null);
}
```

Then , in `render` use `this.state.propVals`  :

```
return <SingleChannel key={channel._id} channel={channel} channelValues={this.state.propVals}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that in if statements you are returning values from callback function, not from `_request()`.

As `_request` is async function, in it callback, you should use `setState` method, to add derived data to current state.
Consider this approach:

```
class Parent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            values: {}
        };

        this._request = this._request.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        // Iterating through channels, and calling `_request` for each channel.
        this.props.channels.forEach(this._request);
    }

    // We are accepting whole `channel` variable, instead of `name`.
    // As we need access to `channel._id` from this function.
    _request(channel) {
        HTTP.call('GET', `https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/${channel.name}`, {
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/vnd.twitchtv.v3+json'
            },
        }, (error, response) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error)
            } else {
                let result;

                if (response.data.stream === null) {
                    result = {
                        streaming: false,
                        game: "Not playing anything"
                    };
                } else {
                    result = {
                        streaming: true,
                        game: response.data.stream.game
                    }
                }

                // Adding result to state. It forces component to rerender with derived data.
                // Note, we need to use `Object.assign` to avoid state mutations.
                this.setState({
                    values: Object.assign({}, this.state.values, {
                        [channel._id]: result,
                    })
                });
            }
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.channels.map(channel => {
                    return (
                        <SingleChannel
                            key={channel._id}
                            channel={channel}
                            channelValues={this.state.values[channel._id]}
                        />
                    );
                })}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: This helped me out a lot so thanks, but the _request method depends on the map function to pass it the name of the channel so I'm not sure how to do that in componentDidMount. I left it how I had it but changed it from returning an object to setting the state and it works to an extent. My map function seems to go crazy now though and continuously iterates through channels over and over.

Comment: @nickkasamis Can you pls provide your current code to pastebin.com, to more clearly understand you?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/2Q7UDTrt - My assumption is that when the component is loaded the array is mapped and for each item it is going to call the request method which should set the state Then output the Strike element passing the current state as props.